# Знак препинания при присоединении к нему указательного местоимения «это»

Tags: запятые, тире

Нужно ли тире и запятые в предложении:

***Вам (,) в этой вкладке (,) нужно написать номер дома, в вашем случае — 66.***

Мне удалось найти правило, которое хорошо объясняет тире после словосочетания "в данном случае", применимо ли оно и к "в вашем случае"?
Становится ли "в этой вкладке" уточнением?

Comment: Что с шапкой вопроса? О чём речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это неполное предложение — предложение, где некие слова или сочетания не произносятся, но предложение понимается слушателем так, как если бы это слово или сочетание было. Например:

> Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо (Т.) (Пропущено слово ‟стрелял”.);
> За окном вагона плыла кочковатая равнина, бежали кустарники, дальние — медленно, ближние — вперегонку (А. Т.). (Пропущено слово ‟бежали”.)
> Голоса офицеров с каждой минутой становились громче, слова — резче, аргументы — непримиримее (Гол.). (Пропущено слово ‟становились”).

Если в таких предложениях пропущено сказуемое, то ставится тире, поэтому в вашем предложении ставится тире (пропущено ‟нужно написать”). [Ссылка на Розенталя, пункт 5.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93)

‟В этой вкладке” это обстоятельство места, а они не обособляются, если нет каких-то специфических причин.

Comment: Спасибо! А нужны ли запятые? На мой взгляд, не нужны.